# Can multiple people work on the same Stencil project simultaneously?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have BigCommerce stencil theme working locally!
Now I am trying to allow multiple people to access my theme. How can I do this?
Can you describe it step by step?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "multiple access"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean It is possible to multiple developer is working on one project at  Same time on localbase stencil theme? Thank you for replay and thank you in advanced!!

Comment: Im waiting for your answer!  can you guide me? ....am new in BC!

Comment: Hi Mark thank you for the help.. Glad help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for two or more people to connect to a server and edit the files that are in the same location and see the changes live while the local instance is running.

Running stencil init/start on the same device might cause a port conflict.

Two people on different computers can edit the files, but the files do not sync between devices without additional intervention. "Additional intervention" would be something like using github for collaborative project work. If you are new to using github or git, I'd recommend the tutorial from atlassian: https://www.atlassian.com/git